# How to select all elements except the one hovered using Vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a social sharing box. Here is my code so far:

```js
const icon = document.querySelectorAll(".icon");
const box = document.querySelector(".social-box");

Array.from(icon).map((i) => {


  i.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
    const el = e.target;
    // el.style.fill = el.getAttribute('data-color');
    el.style.backgroundColor = el.getAttribute("data-color");
  });

  i.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e) {
    let obj = e.relatedTarget;
    while (obj != null) {
      if (obj == this) {
        return;
      }
      obj = obj.parentNode;
    }
    // console.log(e.target)
    const el = e.target;
    el.style.backgroundColor = "";
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  color: #fff;
}

.social-box {
  width: 800px;
  min-height: 60px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: all .1s ease-out;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 9px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.014), 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  /*   transition: all .1s ease-out; */
}

.social-box:hover div {
  background-color: currentcolor;
  fill: black;
}

.icon {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  align-self: stretch;
  flex: 100%;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  fill: white;
}

.twitter {
  background-color: #1DA1F2;
}

.facebook {
  background-color: #1877F2;
}

.reddit {
  background-color: #f04b23;
}

div.whatsapp {
  background-color: #71C169;
}

.flipboard {
  background-color: #bf2626;
}

.buffer {
  background-color: #323b43;
}

.hackernews {
  background-color: #d85623;
}

.email {
  background-color: #6bcce9;
}

.pocket {
  background-color: #ef4056;
}

.linkedin {
  background-color: #2767b1;
}

div .icon:hover {
  /*   background-color: red; */
  fill: white;
  flex: 300%;
}

div .icon:hover span {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .social-box {
    max-width: 150px;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .icon {
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="social-box">
  <div data-color="#1da1f2" class="icon twitter">

    <svg role="img" fill="currenColor" width="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M23.954 4.569c-.885.389-1.83.654-2.825.775 1.014-.611 1.794-1.574 2.163-2.723-.951.555-2.005.959-3.127 1.184-.896-.959-2.173-1.559-3.591-1.559-2.717 0-4.92 2.203-4.92 4.917 0 .39.045.765.127 1.124C7.691 8.094 4.066 6.13 1.64 3.161c-.427.722-.666 1.561-.666 2.475 0 1.71.87 3.213 2.188 4.096-.807-.026-1.566-.248-2.228-.616v.061c0 2.385 1.693 4.374 3.946 4.827-.413.111-.849.171-1.296.171-.314 0-.615-.03-.916-.086.631 1.953 2.445 3.377 4.604 3.417-1.68 1.319-3.809 2.105-6.102 2.105-.39 0-.779-.023-1.17-.067 2.189 1.394 4.768 2.209 7.557 2.209 9.054 0 13.999-7.496 13.999-13.986 0-.209 0-.42-.015-.63.961-.689 1.8-1.56 2.46-2.548l-.047-.02z" /></svg>
    <span>Twitter</span></div>
  <div data-color="#f04b23" class="icon reddit">

    <svg role="img" width="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M12 0A12 12 0 0 0 0 12a12 12 0 0 0 12 12 12 12 0 0 0 12-12A12 12 0 0 0 12 0zm5.01 4.744c.688 0 1.25.561 1.25 1.249a1.25 1.25 0 0 1-2.498.056l-2.597-.547-.8 3.747c1.824.07 3.48.632 4.674 1.488.308-.309.73-.491 1.207-.491.968 0 1.754.786 1.754 1.754 0 .716-.435 1.333-1.01 1.614a3.111 3.111 0 0 1 .042.52c0 2.694-3.13 4.87-7.004 4.87-3.874 0-7.004-2.176-7.004-4.87 0-.183.015-.366.043-.534A1.748 1.748 0 0 1 4.028 12c0-.968.786-1.754 1.754-1.754.463 0 .898.196 1.207.49 1.207-.883 2.878-1.43 4.744-1.487l.885-4.182a.342.342 0 0 1 .14-.197.35.35 0 0 1 .238-.042l2.906.617a1.214 1.214 0 0 1 1.108-.701zM9.25 12C8.561 12 8 12.562 8 13.25c0 .687.561 1.248 1.25 1.248.687 0 1.248-.561 1.248-1.249 0-.688-.561-1.249-1.249-1.249zm5.5 0c-.687 0-1.248.561-1.248 1.25 0 .687.561 1.248 1.249 1.248.688 0 1.249-.561 1.249-1.249 0-.687-.562-1.249-1.25-1.249zm-5.466 3.99a.327.327 0 0 0-.231.094.33.33 0 0 0 0 .463c.842.842 2.484.913 2.961.913.477 0 2.105-.056 2.961-.913a.361.361 0 0 0 .029-.463.33.33 0 0 0-.464 0c-.547.533-1.684.73-2.512.73-.828 0-1.979-.196-2.512-.73a.326.326 0 0 0-.232-.095z" /></svg>

    <span>Reddit</span></div>
  <div data-color="#71c169" class="icon whatsapp">

    <svg width="24" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M17.472 14.382c-.297-.149-1.758-.867-2.03-.967-.273-.099-.471-.148-.67.15-.197.297-.767.966-.94 1.164-.173.199-.347.223-.644.075-.297-.15-1.255-.463-2.39-1.475-.883-.788-1.48-1.761-1.653-2.059-.173-.297-.018-.458.13-.606.134-.133.298-.347.446-.52.149-.174.198-.298.298-.497.099-.198.05-.371-.025-.52-.075-.149-.669-1.612-.916-2.207-.242-.579-.487-.5-.669-.51-.173-.008-.371-.01-.57-.01-.198 0-.52.074-.792.372-.272.297-1.04 1.016-1.04 2.479 0 1.462 1.065 2.875 1.213 3.074.149.198 2.096 3.2 5.077 4.487.709.306 1.262.489 1.694.625.712.227 1.36.195 1.871.118.571-.085 1.758-.719 2.006-1.413.248-.694.248-1.289.173-1.413-.074-.124-.272-.198-.57-.347m-5.421 7.403h-.004a9.87 9.87 0 01-5.031-1.378l-.361-.214-3.741.982.998-3.648-.235-.374a9.86 9.86 0 01-1.51-5.26c.001-5.45 4.436-9.884 9.888-9.884 2.64 0 5.122 1.03 6.988 2.898a9.825 9.825 0 012.893 6.994c-.003 5.45-4.437 9.884-9.885 9.884m8.413-18.297A11.815 11.815 0 0012.05 0C5.495 0 .16 5.335.157 11.892c0 2.096.547 4.142 1.588 5.945L.057 24l6.305-1.654a11.882 11.882 0 005.683 1.448h.005c6.554 0 11.89-5.335 11.893-11.893a11.821 11.821 0 00-3.48-8.413Z" /></svg>

    <span>Whatsapp</span></div>
  <div data-color="#1877f2" class="icon facebook">

    <svg role="img" width="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M23.9981 11.9991C23.9981 5.37216 18.626 0 11.9991 0C5.37216 0 0 5.37216 0 11.9991C0 17.9882 4.38789 22.9522 10.1242 23.8524V15.4676H7.07758V11.9991H10.1242V9.35553C10.1242 6.34826 11.9156 4.68714 14.6564 4.68714C15.9692 4.68714 17.3424 4.92149 17.3424 4.92149V7.87439H15.8294C14.3388 7.87439 13.8739 8.79933 13.8739 9.74824V11.9991H17.2018L16.6698 15.4676H13.8739V23.8524C19.6103 22.9522 23.9981 17.9882 23.9981 11.9991Z" /></svg>
    <span>Facebook<span></div>
  <div data-color="#bf2626" class="icon flipboard">

    <svg width="24" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path d="M0 0v24h24V0H0zm19.2 9.6h-4.8v4.8H9.6v4.8H4.8V4.8h14.4v4.8z" /></svg>
    <span>Flipboard</span></div>
  <div data-color="#323b43" class="icon buffer">
    <svg width="24" height="24" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M23.784 18.24c.287.142.287.267 0 .374l-11.357 5.223c-.287.145-.57.145-.854 0L.213 18.614c-.284-.107-.284-.232 0-.375l2.722-1.23c.284-.14.57-.14.852 0l7.787 3.573c.285.14.57.14.854 0l7.787-3.574c.283-.14.568-.14.852 0l2.717 1.23zm0-6.454c.287.143.287.285 0 .426L12.427 17.44c-.287.104-.57.104-.854 0L.213 12.21c-.284-.143-.284-.284 0-.426l2.722-1.227c.284-.144.57-.144.852 0l7.787 3.57c.285.144.57.144.854 0l7.787-3.57c.283-.144.568-.144.852 0l2.717 1.226zM.214 5.76c-.285-.143-.285-.267 0-.375L11.574.16c.283-.14.57-.14.852 0l11.358 5.23c.287.107.287.232 0 .375l-11.357 5.223c-.287.143-.57.143-.854 0L.213 5.76z" /></svg>

    <span>Buffer</span>
  </div>
  <div data-color="#d85623" class="icon hackernews">

    <svg role="img" width="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M0 24V0h24v24H0zM6.951 5.896l4.112 7.708v5.064h1.583v-4.972l4.148-7.799h-1.749l-2.457 4.875c-.372.745-.688 1.434-.688 1.434s-.297-.708-.651-1.434L8.831 5.896h-1.88z" /></svg>
    <span>HackerNews</span></div>
  <div data-color="#6bcce9" class="icon email">

    <svg role="img" width="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M11.585 5.267c1.834 0 3.558.811 4.824 2.08v.004c0-.609.41-1.068.979-1.068h.145c.891 0 1.073.842 1.073 1.109l.005 9.475c-.063.621.64.941 1.029.543 1.521-1.564 3.342-8.038-.946-11.79-3.996-3.497-9.357-2.921-12.209-.955-3.031 2.091-4.971 6.718-3.086 11.064 2.054 4.74 7.931 6.152 11.424 4.744 1.769-.715 2.586 1.676.749 2.457-2.776 1.184-10.502 1.064-14.11-5.188C-.977 13.521-.847 6.093 5.62 2.245 10.567-.698 17.09.117 21.022 4.224c4.111 4.294 3.872 12.334-.139 15.461-1.816 1.42-4.516.037-4.498-2.031l-.019-.678c-1.265 1.256-2.948 1.988-4.782 1.988-3.625 0-6.813-3.189-6.813-6.812 0-3.659 3.189-6.885 6.814-6.885zm4.561 6.623c-.137-2.653-2.106-4.249-4.484-4.249h-.09c-2.745 0-4.268 2.159-4.268 4.61 0 2.747 1.842 4.481 4.256 4.481 2.693 0 4.464-1.973 4.592-4.306l-.006-.536z" /></svg>
    <span>Email</span></div>
  <div data-color="#ef4056" class="icon pocket">

    <svg role="img" width="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M18.813 10.259l-5.646 5.419c-.32.305-.73.458-1.141.458-.41 0-.821-.153-1.141-.458l-5.646-5.419c-.657-.628-.677-1.671-.049-2.326.63-.657 1.671-.679 2.325-.05l4.511 4.322 4.517-4.322c.66-.631 1.697-.607 2.326.049.631.645.615 1.695-.045 2.326l-.011.001zm5.083-7.546c-.299-.858-1.125-1.436-2.041-1.436H2.179c-.9 0-1.717.564-2.037 1.405-.094.25-.142.511-.142.774v7.245l.084 1.441c.348 3.277 2.047 6.142 4.682 8.139.045.036.094.07.143.105l.03.023c1.411 1.03 2.989 1.728 4.694 2.072.786.158 1.591.24 2.389.24.739 0 1.481-.067 2.209-.204.088-.029.176-.045.264-.06.023 0 .049-.015.074-.029 1.633-.36 3.148-1.036 4.508-2.025l.029-.031.135-.105c2.627-1.995 4.324-4.862 4.686-8.148L24 10.678V3.445c0-.251-.031-.5-.121-.742l.017.01z" /></svg>
    <span>Pocket</span></div>
  <div data-color="#2767b1" class="icon linkedin">

    <svg role="img" width="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M20.447 20.452h-3.554v-5.569c0-1.328-.027-3.037-1.852-3.037-1.853 0-2.136 1.445-2.136 2.939v5.667H9.351V9h3.414v1.561h.046c.477-.9 1.637-1.85 3.37-1.85 3.601 0 4.267 2.37 4.267 5.455v6.286zM5.337 7.433c-1.144 0-2.063-.926-2.063-2.065 0-1.138.92-2.063 2.063-2.063 1.14 0 2.064.925 2.064 2.063 0 1.139-.925 2.065-2.064 2.065zm1.782 13.019H3.555V9h3.564v11.452zM22.225 0H1.771C.792 0 0 .774 0 1.729v20.542C0 23.227.792 24 1.771 24h20.451C23.2 24 24 23.227 24 22.271V1.729C24 .774 23.2 0 22.222 0h.003z" /></svg>
    <span>Linkedin</span></div>

</div>
```

https://codepen.io/codewithjalaj/pen/rNxRzYR

When I hover on one of the icons I want the fill color of the rest of the icons changed to the color present in the `data-color` atrribute.

I tried to do something like this `element.style.fill = element.dataset.color` in javascript but it changes the color of all the icons. Is there any way to select all the icons except the hovered one?

Comment: your codepen seems to work just fine, hat exactly do you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is basically. Keep a reference to the icons array. In the mouse hover event filter your array to exclude the hovered item.

```
const icons = Array.from(icon);
icons.map((i) => { 
  
  i.addEventListener("mouseover", function (e) {
    const el = e.target;
    el.style.backgroundColor = el.getAttribute("data-color");
    icons.filter(x=>x !== el).
    forEach(r=>r.style.fill= r.getAttribute("data-color")) // here the rest of the items are set.
  });
```

Comment: It works after changing the `backgroundColor` to `fill` as icons are svg's.

Comment: Well, I was trying to demonstrate how you can select the others except self.

Answer (score 0):

To change color of the rest of the icons, I selected them with querySelectorAll, took each of them by forEach and changed their color. Then I changed the selected one, so It looks like everything but the selected is changed.

I also removed the rest of the code, changing the colors back, since its not part of the question.

```js
const icon = document.querySelectorAll(".icon");
const box = document.querySelector(".social-box");

Array.from(icon).map((i) => {
  
  
  i.addEventListener("mouseover", function (e) {
    const el = e.target;
    
    const elems = document.querySelectorAll('[data-color]');
    elems.forEach(el => { 
      el.style.backgroundColor = el.getAttribute("data-color");
      console.log(el.getAttribute("data-color"));
    });
    
    el.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  });

 
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  color: #fff;
}

.social-box {
  width: 800px;
  min-height: 60px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: all .1s ease-out;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 9px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 0 4px 5px 0        rgba(0,0,0,0.014), 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
/*   transition: all .1s ease-out; */
}

.social-box:hover div {
  background-color: currentcolor;
  fill: black;
}
.icon {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  align-self: stretch;
  flex: 100%;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  fill: white;
}

.twitter {
  background-color: #1DA1F2;
}
.facebook {
  background-color: #1877F2;
}
.reddit {
  background-color: #f04b23;
}
div.whatsapp {
  background-color: #71C169;
}
.flipboard {
  background-color: #bf2626;
}
.buffer {
  background-color: #323b43;
}
.hackernews {
  background-color: #d85623;
}
.email {
  background-color: #6bcce9;
}
.pocket {
  background-color: #ef4056;
}
.linkedin {
  background-color: #2767b1;
}

div .icon:hover  {
/*   background-color: red; */
  fill: white;
  flex: 300%;
}

div .icon:hover span {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .social-box {
    max-width: 150px;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .icon {
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="social-box">
  <div data-color="#1da1f2" class="icon twitter">

    <svg role="img" fill="currenColor" width="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M23.954 4.569c-.885.389-1.83.654-2.825.775 1.014-.611 1.794-1.574 2.163-2.723-.951.555-2.005.959-3.127 1.184-.896-.959-2.173-1.559-3.591-1.559-2.717 0-4.92 2.203-4.92 4.917 0 .39.045.765.127 1.124C7.691 8.094 4.066 6.13 1.64 3.161c-.427.722-.666 1.561-.666 2.475 0 1.71.87 3.213 2.188 4.096-.807-.026-1.566-.248-2.228-.616v.061c0 2.385 1.693 4.374 3.946 4.827-.413.111-.849.171-1.296.171-.314 0-.615-.03-.916-.086.631 1.953 2.445 3.377 4.604 3.417-1.68 1.319-3.809 2.105-6.102 2.105-.39 0-.779-.023-1.17-.067 2.189 1.394 4.768 2.209 7.557 2.209 9.054 0 13.999-7.496 13.999-13.986 0-.209 0-.42-.015-.63.961-.689 1.8-1.56 2.46-2.548l-.047-.02z" /></svg>
    <span>Twitter</span></div>
  <div data-color="#f04b23" class="icon reddit">

    <svg role="img" width="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M12 0A12 12 0 0 0 0 12a12 12 0 0 0 12 12 12 12 0 0 0 12-12A12 12 0 0 0 12 0zm5.01 4.744c.688 0 1.25.561 1.25 1.249a1.25 1.25 0 0 1-2.498.056l-2.597-.547-.8 3.747c1.824.07 3.48.632 4.674 1.488.308-.309.73-.491 1.207-.491.968 0 1.754.786 1.754 1.754 0 .716-.435 1.333-1.01 1.614a3.111 3.111 0 0 1 .042.52c0 2.694-3.13 4.87-7.004 4.87-3.874 0-7.004-2.176-7.004-4.87 0-.183.015-.366.043-.534A1.748 1.748 0 0 1 4.028 12c0-.968.786-1.754 1.754-1.754.463 0 .898.196 1.207.49 1.207-.883 2.878-1.43 4.744-1.487l.885-4.182a.342.342 0 0 1 .14-.197.35.35 0 0 1 .238-.042l2.906.617a1.214 1.214 0 0 1 1.108-.701zM9.25 12C8.561 12 8 12.562 8 13.25c0 .687.561 1.248 1.25 1.248.687 0 1.248-.561 1.248-1.249 0-.688-.561-1.249-1.249-1.249zm5.5 0c-.687 0-1.248.561-1.248 1.25 0 .687.561 1.248 1.249 1.248.688 0 1.249-.561 1.249-1.249 0-.687-.562-1.249-1.25-1.249zm-5.466 3.99a.327.327 0 0 0-.231.094.33.33 0 0 0 0 .463c.842.842 2.484.913 2.961.913.477 0 2.105-.056 2.961-.913a.361.361 0 0 0 .029-.463.33.33 0 0 0-.464 0c-.547.533-1.684.73-2.512.73-.828 0-1.979-.196-2.512-.73a.326.326 0 0 0-.232-.095z" /></svg>

    <span>Reddit</span></div>
  <div data-color="#71c169" class="icon whatsapp">

    <svg width="24" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M17.472 14.382c-.297-.149-1.758-.867-2.03-.967-.273-.099-.471-.148-.67.15-.197.297-.767.966-.94 1.164-.173.199-.347.223-.644.075-.297-.15-1.255-.463-2.39-1.475-.883-.788-1.48-1.761-1.653-2.059-.173-.297-.018-.458.13-.606.134-.133.298-.347.446-.52.149-.174.198-.298.298-.497.099-.198.05-.371-.025-.52-.075-.149-.669-1.612-.916-2.207-.242-.579-.487-.5-.669-.51-.173-.008-.371-.01-.57-.01-.198 0-.52.074-.792.372-.272.297-1.04 1.016-1.04 2.479 0 1.462 1.065 2.875 1.213 3.074.149.198 2.096 3.2 5.077 4.487.709.306 1.262.489 1.694.625.712.227 1.36.195 1.871.118.571-.085 1.758-.719 2.006-1.413.248-.694.248-1.289.173-1.413-.074-.124-.272-.198-.57-.347m-5.421 7.403h-.004a9.87 9.87 0 01-5.031-1.378l-.361-.214-3.741.982.998-3.648-.235-.374a9.86 9.86 0 01-1.51-5.26c.001-5.45 4.436-9.884 9.888-9.884 2.64 0 5.122 1.03 6.988 2.898a9.825 9.825 0 012.893 6.994c-.003 5.45-4.437 9.884-9.885 9.884m8.413-18.297A11.815 11.815 0 0012.05 0C5.495 0 .16 5.335.157 11.892c0 2.096.547 4.142 1.588 5.945L.057 24l6.305-1.654a11.882 11.882 0 005.683 1.448h.005c6.554 0 11.89-5.335 11.893-11.893a11.821 11.821 0 00-3.48-8.413Z" /></svg>

    <span>Whatsapp</span></div>
  <div data-color="#1877f2" class="icon facebook">

    <svg role="img" width="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M23.9981 11.9991C23.9981 5.37216 18.626 0 11.9991 0C5.37216 0 0 5.37216 0 11.9991C0 17.9882 4.38789 22.9522 10.1242 23.8524V15.4676H7.07758V11.9991H10.1242V9.35553C10.1242 6.34826 11.9156 4.68714 14.6564 4.68714C15.9692 4.68714 17.3424 4.92149 17.3424 4.92149V7.87439H15.8294C14.3388 7.87439 13.8739 8.79933 13.8739 9.74824V11.9991H17.2018L16.6698 15.4676H13.8739V23.8524C19.6103 22.9522 23.9981 17.9882 23.9981 11.9991Z" /></svg>
    <span>Facebook<span></div>
  <div data-color="#bf2626" class="icon flipboard">

    <svg width="24" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path d="M0 0v24h24V0H0zm19.2 9.6h-4.8v4.8H9.6v4.8H4.8V4.8h14.4v4.8z" /></svg>
    <span>Flipboard</span></div>
  <div data-color="#323b43" class="icon buffer">
    <svg width="24" height="24" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M23.784 18.24c.287.142.287.267 0 .374l-11.357 5.223c-.287.145-.57.145-.854 0L.213 18.614c-.284-.107-.284-.232 0-.375l2.722-1.23c.284-.14.57-.14.852 0l7.787 3.573c.285.14.57.14.854 0l7.787-3.574c.283-.14.568-.14.852 0l2.717 1.23zm0-6.454c.287.143.287.285 0 .426L12.427 17.44c-.287.104-.57.104-.854 0L.213 12.21c-.284-.143-.284-.284 0-.426l2.722-1.227c.284-.144.57-.144.852 0l7.787 3.57c.285.144.57.144.854 0l7.787-3.57c.283-.144.568-.144.852 0l2.717 1.226zM.214 5.76c-.285-.143-.285-.267 0-.375L11.574.16c.283-.14.57-.14.852 0l11.358 5.23c.287.107.287.232 0 .375l-11.357 5.223c-.287.143-.57.143-.854 0L.213 5.76z" /></svg>

    <span>Buffer</span>
  </div>
  <div data-color="#d85623" class="icon hackernews">

    <svg role="img" width="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M0 24V0h24v24H0zM6.951 5.896l4.112 7.708v5.064h1.583v-4.972l4.148-7.799h-1.749l-2.457 4.875c-.372.745-.688 1.434-.688 1.434s-.297-.708-.651-1.434L8.831 5.896h-1.88z" /></svg>
    <span>HackerNews</span></div>
  <div data-color="#6bcce9" class="icon email">

    <svg role="img" width="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M11.585 5.267c1.834 0 3.558.811 4.824 2.08v.004c0-.609.41-1.068.979-1.068h.145c.891 0 1.073.842 1.073 1.109l.005 9.475c-.063.621.64.941 1.029.543 1.521-1.564 3.342-8.038-.946-11.79-3.996-3.497-9.357-2.921-12.209-.955-3.031 2.091-4.971 6.718-3.086 11.064 2.054 4.74 7.931 6.152 11.424 4.744 1.769-.715 2.586 1.676.749 2.457-2.776 1.184-10.502 1.064-14.11-5.188C-.977 13.521-.847 6.093 5.62 2.245 10.567-.698 17.09.117 21.022 4.224c4.111 4.294 3.872 12.334-.139 15.461-1.816 1.42-4.516.037-4.498-2.031l-.019-.678c-1.265 1.256-2.948 1.988-4.782 1.988-3.625 0-6.813-3.189-6.813-6.812 0-3.659 3.189-6.885 6.814-6.885zm4.561 6.623c-.137-2.653-2.106-4.249-4.484-4.249h-.09c-2.745 0-4.268 2.159-4.268 4.61 0 2.747 1.842 4.481 4.256 4.481 2.693 0 4.464-1.973 4.592-4.306l-.006-.536z" /></svg>
    <span>Email</span></div>
  <div data-color="#ef4056" class="icon pocket">

    <svg role="img" width="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M18.813 10.259l-5.646 5.419c-.32.305-.73.458-1.141.458-.41 0-.821-.153-1.141-.458l-5.646-5.419c-.657-.628-.677-1.671-.049-2.326.63-.657 1.671-.679 2.325-.05l4.511 4.322 4.517-4.322c.66-.631 1.697-.607 2.326.049.631.645.615 1.695-.045 2.326l-.011.001zm5.083-7.546c-.299-.858-1.125-1.436-2.041-1.436H2.179c-.9 0-1.717.564-2.037 1.405-.094.25-.142.511-.142.774v7.245l.084 1.441c.348 3.277 2.047 6.142 4.682 8.139.045.036.094.07.143.105l.03.023c1.411 1.03 2.989 1.728 4.694 2.072.786.158 1.591.24 2.389.24.739 0 1.481-.067 2.209-.204.088-.029.176-.045.264-.06.023 0 .049-.015.074-.029 1.633-.36 3.148-1.036 4.508-2.025l.029-.031.135-.105c2.627-1.995 4.324-4.862 4.686-8.148L24 10.678V3.445c0-.251-.031-.5-.121-.742l.017.01z" /></svg>
    <span>Pocket</span></div>
  <div data-color="#2767b1" class="icon linkedin">

    <svg role="img" width="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M20.447 20.452h-3.554v-5.569c0-1.328-.027-3.037-1.852-3.037-1.853 0-2.136 1.445-2.136 2.939v5.667H9.351V9h3.414v1.561h.046c.477-.9 1.637-1.85 3.37-1.85 3.601 0 4.267 2.37 4.267 5.455v6.286zM5.337 7.433c-1.144 0-2.063-.926-2.063-2.065 0-1.138.92-2.063 2.063-2.063 1.14 0 2.064.925 2.064 2.063 0 1.139-.925 2.065-2.064 2.065zm1.782 13.019H3.555V9h3.564v11.452zM22.225 0H1.771C.792 0 0 .774 0 1.729v20.542C0 23.227.792 24 1.771 24h20.451C23.2 24 24 23.227 24 22.271V1.729C24 .774 23.2 0 22.222 0h.003z" /></svg>
    <span>Linkedin</span></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed a couple of what appeared to be extraneous commands in `i.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {` and replaced them with a forEach that iterates over all elements with attribute `data-color` and styles each according to it's associated color specified in the `data-color` attribute.

I also commented out `fill: black;` in the `.social-box:hover div` css declaration. You may want to put that back, but I thought it worked better when not changing the button text to black especially since one of the buttons has a black background.

```js
const icon = document.querySelectorAll(".icon");
const box = document.querySelector(".social-box");

Array.from(icon).map((i) => {
  
  
  i.addEventListener("mouseover", function (e) {
    let allMenuItems = document.querySelectorAll('[data-color]');
    allMenuItems.forEach(menuItem);
  });
  
  function menuItem(item) {
    item.style.backgroundColor = item.getAttribute("data-color");
  }

  i.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
    let obj = e.relatedTarget;
    while (obj != null) {
      if (obj == this) {
        return;
      }
      obj = obj.parentNode;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  color: #fff;
}

.social-box {
  width: 800px;
  min-height: 60px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: all .1s ease-out;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 9px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 0 4px 5px 0        rgba(0,0,0,0.014), 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.09);
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
/*   transition: all .1s ease-out; */
}

.social-box:hover div {
  background-color: currentcolor;
  /*fill: black;*/
}
.icon {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  align-self: stretch;
  flex: 100%;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  fill: white;
}

.twitter {
  background-color: #1DA1F2;
}
.facebook {
  background-color: #1877F2;
}
.reddit {
  background-color: #f04b23;
}
div.whatsapp {
  background-color: #71C169;
}
.flipboard {
  background-color: #bf2626;
}
.buffer {
  background-color: #323b43;
}
.hackernews {
  background-color: #d85623;
}
.email {
  background-color: #6bcce9;
}
.pocket {
  background-color: #ef4056;
}
.linkedin {
  background-color: #2767b1;
}

div .icon:hover  {
/*   background-color: red; */
  fill: white;
  flex: 300%;
}

div .icon:hover span {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .social-box {
    max-width: 150px;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .icon {
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="social-box">
  <div data-color="#1da1f2" class="icon twitter">

    <svg role="img" fill="currenColor" width="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M23.954 4.569c-.885.389-1.83.654-2.825.775 1.014-.611 1.794-1.574 2.163-2.723-.951.555-2.005.959-3.127 1.184-.896-.959-2.173-1.559-3.591-1.559-2.717 0-4.92 2.203-4.92 4.917 0 .39.045.765.127 1.124C7.691 8.094 4.066 6.13 1.64 3.161c-.427.722-.666 1.561-.666 2.475 0 1.71.87 3.213 2.188 4.096-.807-.026-1.566-.248-2.228-.616v.061c0 2.385 1.693 4.374 3.946 4.827-.413.111-.849.171-1.296.171-.314 0-.615-.03-.916-.086.631 1.953 2.445 3.377 4.604 3.417-1.68 1.319-3.809 2.105-6.102 2.105-.39 0-.779-.023-1.17-.067 2.189 1.394 4.768 2.209 7.557 2.209 9.054 0 13.999-7.496 13.999-13.986 0-.209 0-.42-.015-.63.961-.689 1.8-1.56 2.46-2.548l-.047-.02z" /></svg>
    <span>Twitter</span></div>
  <div data-color="#f04b23" class="icon reddit">

    <svg role="img" width="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M12 0A12 12 0 0 0 0 12a12 12 0 0 0 12 12 12 12 0 0 0 12-12A12 12 0 0 0 12 0zm5.01 4.744c.688 0 1.25.561 1.25 1.249a1.25 1.25 0 0 1-2.498.056l-2.597-.547-.8 3.747c1.824.07 3.48.632 4.674 1.488.308-.309.73-.491 1.207-.491.968 0 1.754.786 1.754 1.754 0 .716-.435 1.333-1.01 1.614a3.111 3.111 0 0 1 .042.52c0 2.694-3.13 4.87-7.004 4.87-3.874 0-7.004-2.176-7.004-4.87 0-.183.015-.366.043-.534A1.748 1.748 0 0 1 4.028 12c0-.968.786-1.754 1.754-1.754.463 0 .898.196 1.207.49 1.207-.883 2.878-1.43 4.744-1.487l.885-4.182a.342.342 0 0 1 .14-.197.35.35 0 0 1 .238-.042l2.906.617a1.214 1.214 0 0 1 1.108-.701zM9.25 12C8.561 12 8 12.562 8 13.25c0 .687.561 1.248 1.25 1.248.687 0 1.248-.561 1.248-1.249 0-.688-.561-1.249-1.249-1.249zm5.5 0c-.687 0-1.248.561-1.248 1.25 0 .687.561 1.248 1.249 1.248.688 0 1.249-.561 1.249-1.249 0-.687-.562-1.249-1.25-1.249zm-5.466 3.99a.327.327 0 0 0-.231.094.33.33 0 0 0 0 .463c.842.842 2.484.913 2.961.913.477 0 2.105-.056 2.961-.913a.361.361 0 0 0 .029-.463.33.33 0 0 0-.464 0c-.547.533-1.684.73-2.512.73-.828 0-1.979-.196-2.512-.73a.326.326 0 0 0-.232-.095z" /></svg>

    <span>Reddit</span></div>
  <div data-color="#71c169" class="icon whatsapp">

    <svg width="24" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M17.472 14.382c-.297-.149-1.758-.867-2.03-.967-.273-.099-.471-.148-.67.15-.197.297-.767.966-.94 1.164-.173.199-.347.223-.644.075-.297-.15-1.255-.463-2.39-1.475-.883-.788-1.48-1.761-1.653-2.059-.173-.297-.018-.458.13-.606.134-.133.298-.347.446-.52.149-.174.198-.298.298-.497.099-.198.05-.371-.025-.52-.075-.149-.669-1.612-.916-2.207-.242-.579-.487-.5-.669-.51-.173-.008-.371-.01-.57-.01-.198 0-.52.074-.792.372-.272.297-1.04 1.016-1.04 2.479 0 1.462 1.065 2.875 1.213 3.074.149.198 2.096 3.2 5.077 4.487.709.306 1.262.489 1.694.625.712.227 1.36.195 1.871.118.571-.085 1.758-.719 2.006-1.413.248-.694.248-1.289.173-1.413-.074-.124-.272-.198-.57-.347m-5.421 7.403h-.004a9.87 9.87 0 01-5.031-1.378l-.361-.214-3.741.982.998-3.648-.235-.374a9.86 9.86 0 01-1.51-5.26c.001-5.45 4.436-9.884 9.888-9.884 2.64 0 5.122 1.03 6.988 2.898a9.825 9.825 0 012.893 6.994c-.003 5.45-4.437 9.884-9.885 9.884m8.413-18.297A11.815 11.815 0 0012.05 0C5.495 0 .16 5.335.157 11.892c0 2.096.547 4.142 1.588 5.945L.057 24l6.305-1.654a11.882 11.882 0 005.683 1.448h.005c6.554 0 11.89-5.335 11.893-11.893a11.821 11.821 0 00-3.48-8.413Z" /></svg>

    <span>Whatsapp</span></div>
  <div data-color="#1877f2" class="icon facebook">

    <svg role="img" width="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M23.9981 11.9991C23.9981 5.37216 18.626 0 11.9991 0C5.37216 0 0 5.37216 0 11.9991C0 17.9882 4.38789 22.9522 10.1242 23.8524V15.4676H7.07758V11.9991H10.1242V9.35553C10.1242 6.34826 11.9156 4.68714 14.6564 4.68714C15.9692 4.68714 17.3424 4.92149 17.3424 4.92149V7.87439H15.8294C14.3388 7.87439 13.8739 8.79933 13.8739 9.74824V11.9991H17.2018L16.6698 15.4676H13.8739V23.8524C19.6103 22.9522 23.9981 17.9882 23.9981 11.9991Z" /></svg>
    <span>Facebook<span></div>
  <div data-color="#bf2626" class="icon flipboard">

    <svg width="24" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path d="M0 0v24h24V0H0zm19.2 9.6h-4.8v4.8H9.6v4.8H4.8V4.8h14.4v4.8z" /></svg>
    <span>Flipboard</span></div>
  <div data-color="#323b43" class="icon buffer">
    <svg width="24" height="24" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M23.784 18.24c.287.142.287.267 0 .374l-11.357 5.223c-.287.145-.57.145-.854 0L.213 18.614c-.284-.107-.284-.232 0-.375l2.722-1.23c.284-.14.57-.14.852 0l7.787 3.573c.285.14.57.14.854 0l7.787-3.574c.283-.14.568-.14.852 0l2.717 1.23zm0-6.454c.287.143.287.285 0 .426L12.427 17.44c-.287.104-.57.104-.854 0L.213 12.21c-.284-.143-.284-.284 0-.426l2.722-1.227c.284-.144.57-.144.852 0l7.787 3.57c.285.144.57.144.854 0l7.787-3.57c.283-.144.568-.144.852 0l2.717 1.226zM.214 5.76c-.285-.143-.285-.267 0-.375L11.574.16c.283-.14.57-.14.852 0l11.358 5.23c.287.107.287.232 0 .375l-11.357 5.223c-.287.143-.57.143-.854 0L.213 5.76z" /></svg>

    <span>Buffer</span>
  </div>
  <div data-color="#d85623" class="icon hackernews">

    <svg role="img" width="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M0 24V0h24v24H0zM6.951 5.896l4.112 7.708v5.064h1.583v-4.972l4.148-7.799h-1.749l-2.457 4.875c-.372.745-.688 1.434-.688 1.434s-.297-.708-.651-1.434L8.831 5.896h-1.88z" /></svg>
    <span>HackerNews</span></div>
  <div data-color="#6bcce9" class="icon email">

    <svg role="img" width="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M11.585 5.267c1.834 0 3.558.811 4.824 2.08v.004c0-.609.41-1.068.979-1.068h.145c.891 0 1.073.842 1.073 1.109l.005 9.475c-.063.621.64.941 1.029.543 1.521-1.564 3.342-8.038-.946-11.79-3.996-3.497-9.357-2.921-12.209-.955-3.031 2.091-4.971 6.718-3.086 11.064 2.054 4.74 7.931 6.152 11.424 4.744 1.769-.715 2.586 1.676.749 2.457-2.776 1.184-10.502 1.064-14.11-5.188C-.977 13.521-.847 6.093 5.62 2.245 10.567-.698 17.09.117 21.022 4.224c4.111 4.294 3.872 12.334-.139 15.461-1.816 1.42-4.516.037-4.498-2.031l-.019-.678c-1.265 1.256-2.948 1.988-4.782 1.988-3.625 0-6.813-3.189-6.813-6.812 0-3.659 3.189-6.885 6.814-6.885zm4.561 6.623c-.137-2.653-2.106-4.249-4.484-4.249h-.09c-2.745 0-4.268 2.159-4.268 4.61 0 2.747 1.842 4.481 4.256 4.481 2.693 0 4.464-1.973 4.592-4.306l-.006-.536z" /></svg>
    <span>Email</span></div>
  <div data-color="#ef4056" class="icon pocket">

    <svg role="img" width="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M18.813 10.259l-5.646 5.419c-.32.305-.73.458-1.141.458-.41 0-.821-.153-1.141-.458l-5.646-5.419c-.657-.628-.677-1.671-.049-2.326.63-.657 1.671-.679 2.325-.05l4.511 4.322 4.517-4.322c.66-.631 1.697-.607 2.326.049.631.645.615 1.695-.045 2.326l-.011.001zm5.083-7.546c-.299-.858-1.125-1.436-2.041-1.436H2.179c-.9 0-1.717.564-2.037 1.405-.094.25-.142.511-.142.774v7.245l.084 1.441c.348 3.277 2.047 6.142 4.682 8.139.045.036.094.07.143.105l.03.023c1.411 1.03 2.989 1.728 4.694 2.072.786.158 1.591.24 2.389.24.739 0 1.481-.067 2.209-.204.088-.029.176-.045.264-.06.023 0 .049-.015.074-.029 1.633-.36 3.148-1.036 4.508-2.025l.029-.031.135-.105c2.627-1.995 4.324-4.862 4.686-8.148L24 10.678V3.445c0-.251-.031-.5-.121-.742l.017.01z" /></svg>
    <span>Pocket</span></div>
  <div data-color="#2767b1" class="icon linkedin">

    <svg role="img" width="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M20.447 20.452h-3.554v-5.569c0-1.328-.027-3.037-1.852-3.037-1.853 0-2.136 1.445-2.136 2.939v5.667H9.351V9h3.414v1.561h.046c.477-.9 1.637-1.85 3.37-1.85 3.601 0 4.267 2.37 4.267 5.455v6.286zM5.337 7.433c-1.144 0-2.063-.926-2.063-2.065 0-1.138.92-2.063 2.063-2.063 1.14 0 2.064.925 2.064 2.063 0 1.139-.925 2.065-2.064 2.065zm1.782 13.019H3.555V9h3.564v11.452zM22.225 0H1.771C.792 0 0 .774 0 1.729v20.542C0 23.227.792 24 1.771 24h20.451C23.2 24 24 23.227 24 22.271V1.729C24 .774 23.2 0 22.222 0h.003z" /></svg>
    <span>Linkedin</span></div>

</div>
```